# how to pass data consistently from page to page in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently I want to pass data from edit page to add page. So i pass the query using `{path: '/test/admin/clinicvisit/add', query:{id:this.$route.params.id}}`. I was able to pass the data to add page using the query however sometimes the data may not present when it refreshes a few times. Is there any possible way to make the data consistent stay in the add page ?

`add.vue`

```
  async testRoute(){
      let visitId = this.$route.query.id
      if (visitId){
        let clinicVisit = await this.api.medical.viewClinicVisit(visitId)
        this.inputs = await this.api.medical.optionsClinicVisit()

        this.$set(this.inputs.staff, "item_text", "username")
        this.$set(this.inputs.staff, "item_value", "id")
        this.$set(this.inputs.staff, "items", await this.api.profile.listStaff({}))
        if(clinicVisit.staff){
          this.$set(this.inputs.staff, "value", clinicVisit.staff)
          this.$set(this.inputs.staff, "tmp_value", clinicVisit.staff_detail.name)
        }

    mounted()
   {
    this.testRoute()
   }
```

Comment: Why not store it in the browser "localStorage"?

Comment: how do i store in a browser localstorage?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in multiple ways.

1. Using a `global store`, You can use a library like [`Vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to share the state between the components.
2. Using the [`Local Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), if you want to preserve the data and keep saved after hard refreshing the page.
3. Using [`Session Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), if you want to preserve the data and keep saved during the user session, but whenever the user close the browser tab it will be gone.

Comment: thank you , will considered one of the ways u suggested

Comment: how do i store it as localstorage ? do i save it inside my edit page before passing to add page ?

Comment: Yes, and make sure, if the data are an `object` or an `array` to execute `JSON.stringify(data)` when `set` it in the `local storage`, and  `JSON.parse(data)` when you `get` it from `locale storage`.

Comment: For more resources, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: i set the data into the localstorage using `JSON.stringify(data)`. let say the object has `general_amount`, how i get the data specifically and set to the  input field accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

When you observe that the data is not present after a few refreshes, does it dissapear from the URL in your browser, or does it just not load?

If you want the data to stay more consistently, consider using localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('item_text', 'username') //Save variable in browser data
let item_text = window.localStorage.getItem('item_text') //Get variable from browser data
```

---

EDIT:

If the URL is still present in the browser window, that sounds like a weird loading bug, where your code runs before the route is parsed by Vue.
You can try using a watcher instead of the "mounted" function:

```
watch: {
    $route: {
        immediate: true,
        handler() {
            this.testRoute()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the data does not load however the URL still remain the same with the ID

Comment: Thats weird... Maybe you can try moving your function to an immediate watcher of your $route to ensure the router is loaded before your code runs, I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: `nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` had this error after using watcher

Comment: Have you tried, in your testRoute() function, to `console.log(this.$route.query)` to see if it is properly populated before your function runs. 
I dont know what causes the error you describe, but if it otherwise works in `mounted()` you could try setting a timeout and retrying if the query is not yet populated when you first run the function

Comment: i tried to set a timeout and it helps thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by setting a timeout function in my `edit.vue`.

```
handleCreate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.$router.push({path: '/medical/admin/clinicvisit/add', query:{id:this.$route.params.id}},2000)
        // now 'this' is referencing the Vue object and not the 'setTimeout' scope
        this.loadClinicVisitData = true;
        setTimeout(() => this.loadClinicVisitData = false,1000)
    }
```